# Python: Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

I running into bit of an issue and I'm hoping the stackoverflow crew would be able to help.

I keep getting the error message **Object of type 'NoneType' has no len()** whenever I attempt to separate a class of documents.

The full trace-back is:

```
C:\>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Testing\test.py "C:\Testing\IN" "C:\Testing\Outputs" "C:\Testing\Test.csv"

C:\Testing\IN\000001.000001.xml

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Testing\test.py", line 46, in <module>
    if len(documentclass)==0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

C:\>
```

Here's the code:

```
import csv, sys, os
import shutil
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not (len(sys.argv) == 4):
        print 'USAGE: %s inFolder OutFolder csvFile' % (sys.argv[0])
    else:        
        inFolder    = sys.argv[1]
        outFolder   = sys.argv[2]
        className   = sys.argv[3]

        count = 0        
        for fileName in os.listdir(inFolder):
            if fileName.endswith(".pdf"):                
                baseName = fileName.split('.pdf')[0]
                pdfFile = inFolder+"\\"+baseName+".pdf"
                xmlFile = inFolder+"\\"+baseName+".xml"
                validatedXmlFile = inFolder+"\\"+baseName+".xml.validated.xml"                                
                xmlSize = os.path.getsize(xmlFile)
                pdfSize = os.path.getsize(pdfFile)                
                if xmlSize>0 and pdfSize>0:
                    print
                    print xmlFile
                    count = count + 1
                    tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
                    root_xml = tree.getroot()
                    form_xml = root_xml[0]
                    #form_xml = root_xml[1]
                    documentclass_xml = form_xml.find('DocumentClassGlobal')                    
                    documentclassLocal_xml = form_xml.find('DocumentClassLocal')                
                    #documentclass_xml = form_xml.find('SSMClassID')
                    if documentclass_xml is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclass_xml.find('data').text                       
                    elif documentclassLocal_xml is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclassLocal_xml.find('data').text
                        documentclass = documentclass + "_Local"
                    else:
                        documentclass = ""                        
                    if len(documentclass)==0:
                        documentclass = "UNKNOWN"                
                    print documentclass                 

                    if documentclass == className:                                    
                        if not os.path.exists(outFolder + "\\" + documentclass):
                            os.makedirs(outFolder + "\\" + documentclass)
                        inBaseFile = inFolder + "\\"+baseName
                        outBaseFile = outFolder + "\\" + documentclass+"\\"+baseName                                
                        inFile = inBaseFile+".pdf"
                        outFile = outBaseFile+".pdf"
                        print inFile
                        print outFile
                        shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".pdf", outBaseFile+".pdf")
                        shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".pdf.conf.xml", outBaseFile+".pdf.conf.xml")
                        shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".pdf.multi.txt", outBaseFile+".pdf.multi.txt")
                        shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".pdf.txt", outBaseFile+".pdf.txt")
                        #shutil.move(inBaseFile+".wdb", outBaseFile+".wdb")
                        shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".xml", outBaseFile+".xml")
                        if os.path.exists(inBaseFile+".xml.validated.xml"):
                            shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".xml.validated.xml", outBaseFile+".xml.validated.xml")
                        if os.path.exists(inBaseFile+".xml.validationinfo.xml"):
                            shutil.copy(inBaseFile+".xml.validationinfo.xml", outBaseFile+".xml.validationinfo.xml")


        print '%d files found and copied.' % (count)
```

Obviously, the `if len(documentclass)==`0 is returning the None value. The idea is to assign the None value and the 0 value to documentclass - "Unknown"

Thus far, I have come up with the below, but with no success. Any ideas?

Many Thanks

```
if documentclass_xml is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclass_xml.find('data').text                       
                    elif documentclassLocal_xml is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclassLocal_xml.find('data').text
                        documentclass = documentclass + "_Local"
if documentclass_xml is None:
                        documentclass = "UNKNOWN"                      
                    elif documentclassLocal_xml is None:
                        documentclass = "UNKNOWN"
                    else:
                        documentclass = ""                        
                    if len(documentclass)==0:
                        documentclass = "UNKNOWN"                
                    print documentclass
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback to your post.

Comment: `fileName.split('.pdf')` is not doing, what you think!

Comment: usually `len(documentclass) == 0` in Python is written as `if not documentclass` -- Which will work  even if `documentclass` is `None`.  That said, is it possible for `documentclass_xml.find('data').text` to be `None`?

Comment: Yes, then it should default to documentclasslocal_xml.find('data').text. At any case, both should not be blank as they are used to identify the type of document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were some changes made to DocumentClassGlobal and DocumentClassLocal. Before, these objects were created only if there was a value in documentclass_xml.find('data').text. Now, this rule is ignored and documentclass_xml.find('data').text can be a None value. I made the below adjustment and it did the trick. Thanks mgilson for pointing it out.

```
if documentclass_xml is not None and documentclass_xml.find('data').text is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclass_xml.find('data').text                       
                    elif documentclassLocal_xml is not None and documentclass_xml.find('data').text is not None:
                        documentclass = documentclassLocal_xml.find('data').text
                        documentclass = documentclass + "_Local"
```

Answer (score 3):

The traceback tells you that `documentclass` has the value `None`. You initialized it with:

```
                if documentclass_xml is not None:
                    documentclass = documentclass_xml.find('data').text                       
                elif documentclassLocal_xml is not None:
                    documentclass = documentclassLocal_xml.find('data').text
                    documentclass = documentclass + "_Local"
                else:
                    documentclass = ""
```

so at least one branch of the `if` must assign `None` to it. Accessing the `text` attribute of an `ElementTree` node will return `None` if there is no text content in the node. It has to be the first branch of the condition otherwise the attempt to append `"_Local"` would throw the error.

```
>>> data = ET.fromstring('<test/>')
>>> data.text is None
True
```

Therefore you are accessing an empty `<data/>` node.